# Testflight error could not install <appname> WWDR error due to inactive profile

Tags: ios, testflight

I have uploaded an IOS 8 app through iTunes connect, have setup test users and have invited them to test my app. Those users have installed TestFlight from the App Store and have accepted the terms and conditions. The TestFlight app shows my App with an Install button. When the users click Install and error message appears immediately stating the "Testflight error could not install  WWDR error due to inactive profile"

I have found nothing in searches on that string and a bunch of substrings (including searches on the Testflight, not Apple, website)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The same problem here. Tested with existing apple ID and creating new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the "inactive profile" refers to a provisioning profile and I had several that were inactive. I deleted all of my provisioning profiles and created fresh ones for development and distribution. I uploaded another build and that build installed via TestFlight with no problem.

Comment: Your directions did work for me. I, too, had provision profiles that were still active in Xcode but marked as invalid or invalid (managed by Xcode). I deleted all of them and built a new provisioning profile, validated the app and opened it in TestFlight. I confess, the reasoning for the various locations of the same information still seems confusing. But this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The person who has legal and / or admin rights has to accept the new amendments to the legal documents on iTunes Connect also.

There should be a big yellow box at the top of the screen. (That I ignored for the last 4 days. ^_^ )